# Should I use "from", "among", or "between" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Mary had her head buried ostrich-style in her drawer, choosing **from/among/between** her few
>   date-worthy clothes.

What's the correct preposition(s) and why?

This is the source of my confusion:

[from](https://www.google.com.tw/search?ei=I5YqWpTsMozO0gTS8b-4Cw&q=%22choosing%20from%20her%20clothes%22&oq=%22choosing%20from%20her%20clothes%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l4.25620.25905.0.26012.5.4.0.0.0.0.149.149.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.0.0....0.YCtIbwwreOk) 1 Google result.

[among](https://www.google.com.tw/search?ei=EJYqWpftI4ez0gSzqIDwCQ&q=%22choosing%20among%20her%20clothes%22&oq=%22choosing%20among%20her%20clothes%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1204.1301.0.1423.3.2.0.0.0.0.85.161.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.1eRFhq1HjrM) 1 Google result.

[between](https://www.google.com.tw/search?ei=E5YqWtGULoLl0gST463IBw&q=%22choosing%20between%20her%20clothes%22&oq=%22choosing%20between%20her%20clothes%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...14745.15356.0.15494.7.7.0.0.0.0.155.715.2j4.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.0.0....0.Q0EE-oqCgYg) 0 Google results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of them sound good, because I don't think you're using the right verb here.

You don't *choose* while your head is buried like an ostrich – you *search*. You scavange, you hunt, you scrounge. Then, ultimately, you choose from among your findings – but not while your head is still in the drawer.

> Mary had her head buried ostrich-style in her drawer, scouring for a few date-worthy clothes.

However, if you insist on *choosing*, you don't need any preposition at all:

> Mary had her head buried ostrich-style in her drawer, choosing a few date-worthy clothes.

Comment: *Choosing a few* changes the sense, though. The original has a few items to *choose from*, not to *gather*.

Comment: @Lawrence - I guess it all depends on how chock full of options one might envision that drawer to be.